# How to count the number of customers in a system in different timestamp without using "for loops" in Python

Tags: python, count

I want to count the number of customers in a system in every hour based on their arrival and departure datetime. I can count the number of customers using `for` loops. How can I code the problem without using `for` loops?

here is my code with `for` loops:

```
 for i in range(0,len(time_range),1):
     for j in range(0,len(test),1):
        if (time_range.loc[i,'Time']>= test.loc[j,"Arrival"]) and (time_range.loc[i,'Time']<test.loc[j,"Departure"]):
            time_range.loc[i,"Census"]=time_range.loc[i,"Census"]+1
```

**Inputs:**

***Hourly timestamps:***
[image: photo]

***Arrival and departure times for 3 customers:***
[image: photo]

**Output:**

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Please give us your actual code rather than a picture of your code.  It makes it really hard to help you.

Comment: I edited my post and added the actual code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify slightly:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    time_range.loc[i, "Census"] += sum(
        test.loc[j, "Arrival"] <= time_range.loc[i, "Time"] < test.loc[j, "Departure"]
        for j in range(len(test)))
```

You can change the `+=` to just `=` if you know the `"Census"` field is initially 0.

This code uses that fact that `True` behaves like 1 and `False` behaves like 0 in arithmetic.

I don't know any way of getting rid of the outer loop.